# Replace characters other than A-Za-z0-9 and decimal values with space using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I want to keep alphanumeric characters and also the decimal numbers present in my text string and replace all other characters with space.

For alphanumeric characters, I can use

```
def clean_up(text):
    return re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9]", " ", text)
```

But this will replace all `.` whether they are between two digits or a fullstop or at random locations. I just want to keep the `.` if they come between two digits.
I thought of `[^((A-Za-z0-9)|(\d\.\d))]`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can match and capture the patterns you need to keep and just match any char otherwise. Then, using the lambda expression as the replacement argument, you can either replace with the captured substring or a space.

The patterns are:

- `[+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?` - matches any number
- `[^\W_]` - matches any alphanumeric, Unicode included
- `.` - matches any char (with `re.S` or `re.DOTALL`).

The solution looks like

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'([+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?|[^\W_])|.', re.DOTALL)

def clean_up(text):
    return pattern.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) or " ", text)
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/8tAnrA):

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'([+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?|[^\W_])|.', re.DOTALL)

def clean_up(text):
    return pattern.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) or " ", text)

print( clean_up("+1.2E02 ANT01-TEXT_HERE!") )
```

Output: `+1.2E02 ANT01 TEXT HERE`

Comment: FYI, you may add more exclusion patterns after `|` in the capturing group, e.g. IP address, email patterns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`[^A-Za-z0-9](?!\d)`

You can use Negated Character Class with Negative lookahead.

Comment: This will keep something like `a.1` and `2@3`.

Answer (score 0):

`[...]` is a character set, which match the literal character inside, so `[^((A-Za-z0-9)|(\d\.\d))]` means not to match `[A-Za-z0-9]` and the literal `(`,  `|`, `.` and `)`.

You may try `[^a-zA-Z0-9.]|(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)`:

- `[^a-zA-Z0-9.]` match all non-alphanumeric characters except `.`
- `(?<!\d)\.` match `.` after non-digit
- `\.(?!\d)` match `.` before non-digit

Test run:

```
print(re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9.]|(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)", " ", ".aBc.1e2@3.4F5$6.gHi."))
```

Output:

```
 aBc 1e2 3.4F5 6 gHi
```